# C# Event Handlers getting more and more

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling

I'm writing a simple Chess-Game at the moment.

In my game there are "Chessfields" and "Options". A Chessfield is every field on the board, a option is every move-possibility of a Figure on the field.

So when i click a chessfield, for every option-field i bind a new event-handler.

**Like so:**

```
private void Chessfield_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // ... some other stuff

    PlaceOptions();

    // ... some other stuff
}
```

**Where the function PlaceOptions() does this:**

```
private void PlaceOptions(List<(int, int)> Options, int SourceX, int SourceY)
{
    foreach ((int, int) option in Options)
    {
        // ... some other stuff

        chessfield.MouseDown -= Chessfield_Click;

        // should remove all existing handlers for that field
        foreach (MouseButtonEventHandler optionClickHandler in _recentOptionClickHandlers)
        {
            chessfield.MouseDown -= optionClickHandler;
        }

        chessfield.MouseDown += (sender, e) => Option_Click(sender, e, chessfield, SourceX, SourceY);
        _recentOptionClickHandlers.Add((sender, e) => Option_Click(sender, e, chessfield, SourceX, SourceY));

        // ... some other stuff
    }
}
```

`_recentOptionClickHandlers` is a global variable that stores every handler i added to any option-field:

```
private List<MouseButtonEventHandler> _recentOptionClickHandlers = new List<MouseButtonEventHandler>();
```

**Now:** every time i click on a chessfield, the `Chessfield_Click()` handler only gets called once.

**But there comes the problem:**
When i then click on a option-field (so a possible move of a figure), all recently clicked normal chessfields get moved to that field, because all the previous handlers are still active, but i allready deleted them by calling:

```
foreach (MouseButtonEventHandler optionClickHandler in _recentOptionClickHandlers)
{
    chessfield.MouseDown -= optionClickHandler;
}
```

And the more i click any fields, the more event handlers are getting called (1st time: 1 handler; 2nd time: 2 handlers; 3rd time: 4 handlers; ...)

This problem really drives me crazy since 2 days now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you have invented a new type of chess? Social chess, when you move a piece, all pieces move there :) All jokes aside, do note that every where you write `(sender, e) => Option_Click(...)` you're creating a new instance, so basically you're adding one such instance to MouseDown and adding another such instance to `_recentOptionClickHandlers`, make sure you use the same instance in these two and I think you should be fine.

Comment: You're making a lamda.. your mousedown += and your recentoptionclickhandlers += are not pointing to the same objects

Comment: So when i do: `MouseButtonEventHandler optionClickHandler = (sender, e) => Option_Click(sender, e, chessfield, SourceX, SourceY);` before, and use this object twice, it should be fine?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! @BugFinder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't test it now and can't post a comment either, so I'll reply here.

I think that the handler added to `_recentOptionClickHandlers` is not the same that you're registering for the `MouseDown` event, as you're creating a new `delegate` before adding it to your list.

You should try something like this:

```
EventHandler evt = (sender, e) => Option_Click(sender, e, chessfield, SourceX, SourceY);
chessfield.MouseDown += evt;
_recentOptionClickHandlers.Add(evt);
```

Comment: that was exactly what i needed, thanks to @STT and @BugFinder!